# How to Write VBA Conditional Formatting Between Cell Values (Invalid procedure, Call or argument)

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I am trying to apply conditional formatting to cells when they are between certain values.

I'm getting Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument.

I need to use VBA to do this as the cell references (that I want to apply across) get messed up when I insert rows.

I've looked at multiple pieces of sample code which approach the problem in different ways but when I try to replicate have no success. I'm pretty new to VBA (and self taught) so this might be a very simple, obvious issue.

```
With Sheets("Reconciliation").Range("K9:K66")
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=x1CellValue, Operator:=x1Between, Formula1:="=-10", Formula2:="=-0.1"
    .FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    .FormatConditions.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

SOLUTION

When I use the macro recorder I get:

```
Range("K9:K66").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-24
    Range("K9:K66,O9:O66").Select
    Range("O9").Activate
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=-10", Formula2:="=-0.1"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

I modified this to be:

```
Range("K9:K66,O9:O66").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=-10", Formula2:="=-0.1"
    Range("K9:K66,O9:O66").FormatConditions(Range("K9:K66,O9:O66").FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Range("K9:K66,O9:O66").FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Range("K9:K66,O9:O66").FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("K9:K66,O9:O66").FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

and it works now

Comment: Have you learned about the Macro Recorder? This sounds like an ideal situation to use that, see what code it generates and then manipulate that to be more robust/generic.

Comment: I have tried this but the recorder always selects the cells and I am trying to avoid using select - I could do this if there are no other solutions through

Comment: What you do, is use the generated macro via the recorder as a base line. You are absolutely correct to not to want to use select. You should just look for the "magic lines" in the recorded macro and build off that by using named ranges that are selected/configured dynamically etc.

Comment: Thankyou, it seems to have worked now when I made the above modifications. I must have changed thing incorrectly before. Thanks for your help

Comment: Please post your answer, as an answer to let people know question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

When I use the macro recorder I get:

```
Range("K9:K66").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-24
    Range("K9:K66,O9:O66").Select
    Range("O9").Activate
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=-10", Formula2:="=-0.1"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

I modified this to be:

```
Range("K9:K66,O9:O66").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=-10", Formula2:="=-0.1"
    Range("K9:K66,O9:O66").FormatConditions(Range("K9:K66,O9:O66").FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Range("K9:K66,O9:O66").FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Range("K9:K66,O9:O66").FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("K9:K66,O9:O66").FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

and it works now